# How to add descriptive text to a sentence end?

Tags: phrases

I have seen a lot of sentences that end with another (typically) smaller sentences, often starting with "with", which give a description of some word that was introduced in the main sentence. I do not remember any specific sentence right now (sorry), but I want to compose such a sentence in my academic paper. This is how I write it:

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed, **with its results shown in table 3**.

I am suspicious about the highlighted part. I don't know the underlying grammar for it. Is it correct as is? Should there be tense consistency (past-present-future) between main sentence (first part) and the descriptive part? Or always progressive verbs (-ing) should be used? For example, which one of the following is preferred?

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed, with its results being shown in table 3.

Or

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed, with its results that were shown in table 3.

Comment: _Bonferroni's post hoc test was employed; the results of which are shown in table 3._  However, I find nothing wrong with your initial sentence other than the unnecessary hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed, with its results shown in
>   table 3.

You are right, IMO, to be suspicious of your sentence.  Normally such a with-clause modifies or qualifies:

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed, *with the confidence interval adjusted to ___*.

But here your with clause is simply an addendum to the main idea, not a qualification, so a simple "and" would suffice:

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed and its results are shown in
>   table 3.

or a semicolon:

> Bonferroni’s post-hoc test was employed; its results are shown in
>   table 3.

Comment: then how should I correct the my sentence to keep using _with_? I like using with for adding qualification or whatever you said to my sentence. What is the correct format?

Comment: Your second quote seems to be using the same wording style as mine. what is the difference?

Comment: I wasn't talking about "style" but about the kind of idea that typically occurs in such a with-clause.  The fact that the results are shown in Table 3 has nothing to do with the test per se, or how it was used, the parameters involved, etc.